# Is it possible to protect a VPS from unnoticed manipulation by its host?

Tags: security, vps

From what I have read, it's not feasible to know if VPS's data has been spied on by the host; But is it at least possible to protect the system against manipulations, such as the host installing a script on it?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to prevent but it's possible to detect:

- using HIDS to monitor changes in system state.
- taking checksums on file system to detect new & modified files.

Instead of technical prevention you could broaden your scope to legal actions. Make sure you have a contract that forbids this kind of activity with a mutually agreed penalty. Now, if you detect such activities with the methods mentioned above, your service provider will be liable. (In many countries this might already be illegal even without a contract, but there's no harm in explicitly ensuring it, and the contract may contain more stricter sanctions than the law.)

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed guide? I'm a total noob here. :-)

Comment: @HappyFace take a look at https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-ossec-hids-on-a-centos-7-server - there are many other such tutorials available.

Answer (score 1):

That depends. In generally: NO.

In particular: Hyper-V Shielded VM's are exactly that - VM's protected from the host.
But as "VPS" in the question context often comes as in "rental VM's by some ISP" - good luck finding a provider offering you this.